# "Remember me" functionality is not working

Tags: html, .net

I want to create a login page with remember me (checkbox) functionality. I tried
almost all the codes available on the internet but nothing was worked properly.I want to code in asp.net (web form).

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    UserName:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    Password:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    Remember me:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemember" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Login_Click" />
</form>
```

**WEB CONFIG**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**.aspx.cs code**

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
        {
            txtUserName.Text = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
            txtPassword.Attributes["value"] = Request.Cookies["Password"].Value;
        }
    }
    if (chkRemember.Checked)
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    }
    Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
    Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ASP dot net person ! Still, I would say the logic you used is wrong (my assumption).

First think about what "Remeber me" check box should does. If a user used to log in daily in to your web application then he don't want to enter his username & password daily. Which doesn't mean that you have to explicitly try to set his username & password in the respective boxes. Also `setting user's credential in a cookie is unethical. You should not store his credentials in a cookie which can be accessed easily in client side.`

Rather than doing that logic (if (chkRemember.Checked)) try to increase the session cookies expiry date as follows. So that when user tries to enter the website (say something.com) it directly forwards him to homepage.

```
if (chkRemember.Checked)
{
    Response.Cookies["sessionCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
}
else
{
    Response.Cookies["sessionCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

}
```

I guess, `if (!IsPostBack)` part is not required. Rather than doing that write a logic in your `logout` page to set the sessionCookie expiry to -1 days !!

Also by this, you can have a condition (as 30 days given above),

```
if(expiry of sessionCookie is more than 30 days) {
Print "You need to login again. System won't allow you to be logged in for more than 30 days"
}
```

Comment: There is any other way(Javascript, except PHP) to implement remember me functionality?

Comment: What actually you are expecting by remember me functionality ?

Comment: In my project, I want to implement this functionality I tried all the available code on the internet but nothing was suited to me